# "/" removed from url when invoking it from database to load a background image using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, url-rewriting

I have urls stored in my database and I can't manage to use them as background images for cards.

in the database there is a "cocktails" table with a "image" column where are stored urls as strings

```
<% @cocktails.each do |cocktail| %>
  <div { background-image: url(<%= cocktail.image %>) }></div>
<% end %>
```

looks like that in the navigator inspector:

```html
<div {="" background-image:=""url(https:="" weatherinternal.com="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2019="" 04="" book-claims-to-shed-light-on-john-belushis-final-drug-fueled-hours.jpg)="" }=""></div>
```

the "/" seemed to be removed and the image doesn't display

when I write `<%= cocktail.image %>` it displays the link in the right format
and the image displayed correctly using a `<img>` or the rails image helper.

I guess in the navigator the html should looks like something like that

```html
<div {="" background-image:=""url(https:/weatherinternal.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/book-claims-to-shed-light-on-john-belushis-final-drug-fueled-hours.jpg)="" }=""></div>
```

Comment: What happens if you do `<div { background-image: url("<%= cocktail.image %>") }></div>` like this?

Comment: it doesn't change anything beside adding ```"``` I tried ```<div { background-image: url(<%= "#{cocktail.image}" %>) }></div>```, doesn't work either

Comment: Try `<%= %(#{cocktail.image}) %>`